# How to add a sortable table on ActiveAdmin's show page inside a tab?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

Consider the following scenario: I have a resource with `index` and `show` pages in `ActiveAdmin`, and on the show page I have more [`Tabs`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/gregbell/active_admin/ActiveAdmin/Views/Tabs).

[image: example picture showing four tabs in resource show page]

In some (possibly more than one) of those `Tabs` I would like to display information related to the resource in tabular form, with sortable columns.
I would also require the application to stay on the selected `Tab` while changing sort order for the tables.

How to achieve this in `ActiveAdmin`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately ActiveAdmin doesn't seem to support this out-of-the-box, but it can be achieved.

in the `ActiveAdmin.register` call (usually in `lib/admin/resource.rb`) this would create a table for the `resource`'s `some_connection` data:

```
tab "Tab 2" do
  table_for resource.some_connection do
    column :name
    ...
  end
end
```

Unfortunately this is not a sortable table, so we should simply add the following option hash:

```
{:sortable => true, :class => 'index_table'}
```

like so:

```
table_for resource.some_connection, {:sortable => true, :class => 'index_table'} do
```

Well, this will almost work. Unfortunately selecting a sort column will take you back to the first `Tab`, but the sorting will be stored in the URL (in `whatever/your/page/address/is?order=name_asc` format).

To solve this issue I monkey-patched `ActiveAdmin's` `TableFor` class with the following (in a new file I created in my project structure, e.g.:  `ext/active_admin/views/table_for`):

```
module ActiveAdmin
  module Views
    class TableFor

      def build(obj, *attrs)
        options         = attrs.extract_options!
        @sortable       = options.delete(:sortable)
        @collection     = obj.respond_to?(:each) && !obj.is_a?(Hash) ? obj : [obj]
        @resource_class = options.delete(:i18n)
        @resource_class ||= @collection.klass if @collection.respond_to? :klass
        @columns        = []
        @row_class      = options.delete(:row_class) 
        @anchor         = options.delete(:anchor)
        @sort_key_prefix = ''
        @sort_key_prefix = @anchor.to_s + '_' unless @anchor.nil?

        build_table
        super(options)
        columns(*attrs)
      end

      def build_table_header(col)
        classes  = Arbre::HTML::ClassList.new

        sort_key = sortable? && col.sortable? && col.sort_key

        params   = request.query_parameters.except :page, :order, :commit, :format

        classes << 'sortable'                         if sort_key
        classes << "sorted-#{current_sort[1]}"        if sort_key && current_sort[0] == @sort_key_prefix + sort_key
        classes << col.html_class

        if sort_key
          th class: classes do
            link_to col.pretty_title, params: params, order: "#{@sort_key_prefix}#{sort_key}_#{order_for_sort_key(@sort_key_prefix + sort_key)}", anchor: @anchor
          end
        else
          th col.pretty_title, class: classes
        end
      end

    end
  end
end
```

Basically I added an anchor parameter in options, and using this we can get back to the tab where the table is after selecting a sort criteria. Those criteria's name are extended with this anchor as a prefix, so having columns named the same in different tabs would not mess up the sorting of the different tables. (Currently I use the anchor as the prefix, but this could be changed to a fully separate option parameter to support more tables in one `Tab`)

I use an initializer to load the monkey patch, which simply requires the file which contains the code from above (`ext/active_admin/views/table_for` in my example):

```
monkey_patches.rb
-----------------
require 'ext/active_admin/views/table_for'
```

These changes require us to slightly modify the way we build the table (we have to retrieve the sort settings from the `params` and apply them to our data):

```
tab_name = "Tab 2"
tab tab_name do
  tab_anchor = tab_name.parameterize('_')

  data = resource.some_conection
  unless params['order'].nil?
    order = params['order'].to_s.sub(tab_anchor + '_', '').sub("_asc", " ASC").sub("_desc", " DESC")
    data = data.order(order) unless order.nil?
  end

  table_for data, { anchor: tab_anchor, :sortable => true, :class => 'index_table'} do
    column :name
    ...
  end
end
```

This is the result (here the table is actually put into a [`Panel`](http://activeadmin.info/docs/12-arbre-components.html#panels), and the `anchor` points to that):

[image: Example sortable table in Tab]

Comment: I tried your solution, first of all adding: require 'ext/active_admin/views/table_for' throws error while running the server, saying it's not found. While running without it , it's not sorting my data and only jumps which does indicate me that it's pointed to the right tab

Comment: @Fay007 Disclaimer: It's a 4 year old answer, most likely a lot has changed in active admin since then, but I haven't followed those changes, so it is more than likely that this is NOT the way to achieve what you want.

The file `ext/active_admin/views/table_for` is a file you should create (with the monkey-patch as content), so if your server cannot find it, then maybe you named it differently or forgot to include it in your solution.
I'll edit the answer to be more explicit about this :)

Answer (score -1):

Actually, ActiveAdmin does support this.

To sort the table, call the `order()` method and pass the column name and either `desc/asc`, like do:

```
table_for boat.bookings.order('created_at desc') do
  column :name
  column :created_at
end
```

Thanks to Ryan Bates' screencast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/284-active-admin?view=asciicast